# Using Chart.js for Application

Tags: javascript, charts

I am trying to create a line and pie chart using graph.js, the line chart is showing up but the pie chart is not. Is there anything wrong with my html? The two data variables come respectively come from graph.js (the line graph, which is the first variable) and piegraph.js, which is the second data variable.

```
    <script src="Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="graph.js"></script> 
    <script src="piegraph.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>

    <canvas id="myChart" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
    <script>
        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
        var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data,options);

    </script>
<canvas id="myPie" width="300" height= "300"></canvas>
<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myPie").getContext("2d");
    var myPie = new Chart(ctx[0]).Pie(data,options);

var data = {
labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
datasets: [
    {
        label: "My First dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
    },
    {
        label: "My Second dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
    }
]
};
var data = [
    {
    value: 300,
    color:"#F7464A",
    highlight: "#FF5A5E",
    label: "Red"
},
{
    value: 50,
    color: "#46BFBD",
    highlight: "#5AD3D1",
    label: "Green"
},
{
    value: 100,
    color: "#FDB45C",
    highlight: "#FFC870",
    label: "Yellow"
}
  ]
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you show what your data is ?

Comment: why for the line chart is the argument for your Chart() function ctx, but for the pie chart the argument is ctx[0]?

Comment: @Branden, I was following the tutorial on Chart.js website. For some reason it said to use [0} for the pie chart.

Comment: I think it has to do with that [0] refers to a regular pie chart and [1] refers to a pie chart with a donut whole

Comment: for pie chart change var ctx into var ctx2 and then also from last line from ctx[0] to ctx2

Comment: so should it look like this: var ctx2 = document.getElementById("myPie").getContext("2d");
  var myPie = new Chart(ctx2).Pie(data,options);

Comment: yes, did it worked ?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing two things wrong first you are using ctx[0] for pie chart where it's variable is ctx.

Second you are overwriting data variable with same value so below here i changed your code.

HTML

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<canvas id="myPie" width="300" height= "300"></canvas>
```

Javascript code

```
//Data for Bar Graph
var data = {
labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
datasets: [
    {
        label: "My First dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
    },
    {
        label: "My Second dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
    }
]
};
// Drawing Bar Chart From Your Above data
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data);

//Data for Pie Chart.
var data2 = [
    {
    value: 300,
    color:"#F7464A",
    highlight: "#FF5A5E",
    label: "Red"
},
{
    value: 50,
    color: "#46BFBD",
    highlight: "#5AD3D1",
    label: "Green"
},
{
    value: 100,
    color: "#FDB45C",
    highlight: "#FFC870",
    label: "Yellow"
}
];
var ctx2 = document.getElementById("myPie").getContext("2d");
var myPie = new Chart(ctx2).Pie(data2);
```

See this code [live at Here](https://jsfiddle.net/mabdullah353/xsq4vrg9/)